# How to solve this query in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I have this records in MySQL below

```
RecID | Description | Date | Hits | IsPublished 
1; "Test"; 04/10/2012; 45; True
2; "Test 1"; 04/10/2012; 37; True
3; "Test 2"; 05/10/2012; 12; True
4; "Test 3"; 05/10/2012; 13; True
5; "Test 4"; 07/10/2012; 14; True
6; "Test 5"; 07/10/2012; 25; True
7; "Test 4"; 08/10/2012; 23; True
8; "Test 5"; 08/10/2012; 35; True
9; "Test 9"; 12/10/2012; 7; True
```

Would like to achieve the following

```
9; "Test 9"; 12/10/2012; 7; True 
8; "Test 5"; 08/10/2012; 35; True
4; "Test 3"; 05/10/2012; 13; True
```

Basically, the first rule is to group the date which is 08/10/2012, 07/10/2012 and 05/10/2012 and 04/10/2012. Use this 08/10/2012 as a starting point. Then remove any dates that is close to each other (min 1 day).

BTW ... this is an Australian date (DD/MM/YYYY). Therefore, the result is 08/10/2012, 05/10/2012. Out of these 2 "valid" days and then pick the record that has more hits on that day. Then set the others as IsPublished = false.

Any ideas to do this in MySQL?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the rules?  I don't understand what you mean... "Basically, the first rule is to group the date which is 08/10/2012, 07/10/2012 and 05/10/2012 and 04/10/2012. Use this 08/10/2012 as a based. Then remove any dates that is to each other (min 1 day)." doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Adam: This is an Australian date (DD/MM/YYYY). Basically we need to eliminate any record that coming continuously so as you can see 08/10/2012 and 07/10/2012 is close (1 day apart) so we need to remove the 07/10/2012 ones. Then it found next one which 05/10/2012 and then we kept this but delete 04/10/2012 ones. Make sense?

Comment: @AdamPlocher I agree. I have no idea from the question what is the desired result.

Comment: I adjust the question to make it more clearly.

Comment: Ahh makes much more sense now :).  Damn my American dates.

Comment: @AdamPlocher: :) The tricky bit is actually using the latest one as starting point. Then look the next one down and if it's only 1 day apart then remove that. Then find other active one down and keep that day. Move on to next one and it's close within 1 day then remove that so on and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the dates that have no other rows with a day larger by 1:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Date
    FROM table_name t1
    LEFT JOIN table_name t2
      ON DATE_ADD(t1.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = t2.Date
    WHERE t2.RecId IS NULL
```

Then find the max hits for these dates:

```
  SELECT Date, MAX(Hits) as maxHits
  FROM table_name
  WHERE Date IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Date
    FROM table_name t1
    LEFT JOIN table_name t2
      ON DATE_ADD(t1.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = t2.Date
    WHERE t2.RecId IS NULL )
  GROUP BY Date
```

Finally, update all rows that don't match these dates and maxHits:

```
UPDATE table_name toUpdate, (    
  SELECT Date, MAX(Hits) as maxHits
  FROM table_name
  WHERE Date IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Date
    FROM table_name t1
    LEFT JOIN table_name t2
      ON DATE_ADD(t1.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = t2.Date
    WHERE t2.RecId IS NULL )
  GROUP BY Date) source
SET toUpdate.IsPublished = false
WHERE toUpdate.Date != source.Date OR toUpdate.Hits != source.maxHits
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. I ran the first section of query (First find the dates that have no other rows with a day larger by 1) and compare with actual records. Found the result is different.

Comment: What dates are you getting if not 8/10 and 5/10? Are there times associated with these dates?  If so, you would need to cast all datetimes to dates first using date() function...

Comment: One other thing - can you verify that MySQL is aware you are using 'Australian' dates?  You can run `SELECT *, DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM table_name` and you should get the Date field incremented by 1 day.  If it's incremented any differently, then this could be your problem.

Comment: Ah I realise what issue is. In my real data: I have a single record for let say 08/10/2012, 2 records in 06/10/2012, 2 records in 05/10/2012. In this case, it will show only for 06/10/2012 !!! But I need a single show up as well which is 08/10/2012 as well.

Comment: I made a change in question ... See RecID = 9.